# Message read by user signalR chat

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I created chat app with SignalR. I have question about is there way in signalR from where I can identify if user read message or not ? 
If he open/read message then, can I able to send some notification to application to update info in database ?

I created application using MVC5 & c#.

Comment: Not out the box, when the user is capable of seeing it, send back a message saying so

Comment: I tried same kind of solution when I show message on client side `chat.server.readRecepient();` but it has been call 2 times from 2nd client. Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean it has been called 2 times from 2nd client?